# Python smtplib.SMTP('localhost') hangs forever

Tags: postfix-mta, smtplib

I have a server with installed Postfix SMTP service, and I can send messages using bash like this:

```
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line" user@example.com
```

But when I'm trying to do the same with Python it hangs forever:

```
import smtplib
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.send_message('')
```

The script hangs on the second line, and it is not clear why.
I've checked the configuration of iptables (it is empty) and I still able to send messages with bash command.

"telnet localhost 25" also works fine, port is open.

Postfix config file:

```
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = /etc/mailname
```

Answer (score 0):

[send_message()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html?highlight=smtplib#smtplib.SMTP.send_message) expects an [EmailMessage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage) not a string. Currently it appears to hang because postfix is waiting for you to tell it to do something, you can enable debugging output using [set_debuglevel()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html?highlight=smtplib#smtplib.SMTP.set_debuglevel).

Here's a simple example that should work:

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
import smtplib

msg = EmailMessage()
msg["From"] = "user@example.com"                                                    
msg["To"] = "another-user@example.com"
msg["Subject"] = "Test message subject."                                            
msg.set_content("Test message.")                                                    

s = smtplib.SMTP("localhost")
s.set_debuglevel(1)
s.send_message(msg)
s.quit()
```